# Non-dependent list type Coq

Tags: coq

I'm trying to define a non-dependent `list` type in Coq, but I cannot figure out a way to do that. I managed to define `ndList` axiomatically, modifying Coq's `list` definition. Here's my work so far:

```
Axiom ndList : forall C: Type, Type.
Axiom nil : forall C, ndList C.
Axiom cons : forall C, forall (c: C) (l: ndList C), ndList C.
Arguments nil {_}.
Arguments cons {_} _ _.
Axiom el : forall (C L: Type), forall (a: L) (s: ndList C)
    (l: forall (x: C) (z: L), L), L.
Axiom c1 : forall (C L: Type), forall (a: L) (l: forall (x: C) (z: L), L), 
  el C L a nil l = a.
Axiom c2 : forall (C L: Type), forall (s: ndList C) (c: C) (a: L) 
  (l: forall (x: C) (z: L), L), 
    el C L a (cons c s) l = l c (el C L a s l).
Axiom c_eta : forall (C L: Type), forall (a: L) (l: forall (x: C) (z: L), L)
  (t: forall y: ndList C, L) (s: ndList C) (eq1: t nil = a) 
  (eq2: forall (x: C) (z: ndList C), t (cons x z) = l x (t z)),
    el C L a s l = t s.
```

Is there a way to define `ndList` as an `Inductive` type?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Any particular reason for wanting to define this axiomatically? The definition of list as an inductive type is available online: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Init.Datatypes.html.

Comment: No, actually there isn't.

I know that definition, but `list_rec` makes use of a dependent type `P : list A -> Set`. On the contrary, I want to define a slightly different list type, in which `P` does not depend on `list A`. Anyway, I managed to define that axiomatically (see the updated question's text), but I wonder if there's an inductive equivalent.

Comment: Your `e1` is just the special case of `list_rect` where `P := fun _ : list C => L`.  (See also `Coq.Lists.List.fold_right`.)

Comment: I remember your previous question about equality types.  In Coq, *any* inductive type automatically supports dependent induction and recursion principles. There is no way to prevent that.  Note that if you have a non-dependent elimination principle, you can use it to write recursive functions, but you won't be able to prove anything by induction.

Comment: You could also sort of do something like this with `Definition ndList (C:Type) : Type := forall T:Type, T -> (C->T) -> T.`  (Which apparently is what you once had to do in much older versions of Coq.)  The big show-stopper for that, though, is that because of universe hierarchies you wouldn't be able to directly apply the recursion operator to types that involve `list` themselves (so e.g. you would have to do a by-hand definition for `append`).

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim ok, I think I finally got it. @DanielSchepler, could you please give me a hint on defining  `append` without recursion?

Comment: You can use `Scheme list_ind_non_dep := Minimality for list Sort Type` to define a non-dependent principle (cf [doc](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual015.html#hevea_command234)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "non-dependent" list type is provably isomorphic to Coq's `list` type:

```
Axiom ndList : forall C: Type, Type.
Axiom nil : forall C, ndList C.
Axiom cons : forall C, forall (c: C) (l: ndList C), ndList C.
Arguments nil {_}.
Arguments cons {_} _ _.
Axiom el : forall (C L: Type), forall (a: L) (s: ndList C)
                                      (l: forall (x: C) (z: L), L), L.
Axiom c1 : forall (C L: Type), forall (a: L) (l: forall (x: C) (z: L), L),
      el C L a nil l = a.
Axiom c2 : forall (C L: Type), forall (s: ndList C) (c: C) (a: L)
                                      (l: forall (x: C) (z: L), L),
      el C L a (cons c s) l = l c (el C L a s l).
Axiom c_eta : forall (C L: Type), forall (a: L) (l: forall (x: C) (z: L), L)
                 (t: forall y: ndList C, L) (s: ndList C) (eq1: t nil = a)
                 (eq2: forall (x: C) (z: ndList C), t (cons x z) = l x (t z)),
      el C L a s l = t s.

Section iso.
  Context {A : Type}.
  Definition list_to_ndList : list A -> ndList A
    := list_rect (fun _ => ndList A)
                 nil
                 (fun x _ xs => cons x xs).
  Definition ndList_to_list (ls : ndList A) : list A
    := el A (list A)
          Datatypes.nil
          ls
          Datatypes.cons.
  Lemma list_eq (ls : list A) : ndList_to_list (list_to_ndList ls) = ls.
  Proof.
    unfold ndList_to_list, list_to_ndList.
    induction ls as [|x xs IHxs];
      repeat first [ progress simpl
                   | progress rewrite ?c1, ?c2
                   | congruence ].
  Qed.
  Lemma ndList_eq (ls : ndList A) : list_to_ndList (ndList_to_list ls) = ls.
  Proof.
    unfold ndList_to_list, list_to_ndList.
    transitivity (el A (ndList A) nil ls cons); [ symmetry | ]; revert ls;
      match goal with
      | [ |- forall ls, @?LHS ls = @?RHS ls ]
        => intro ls; apply (c_eta _ _ _ _ RHS ls)
      end;
      repeat first [ progress simpl
                   | progress intros
                   | progress rewrite ?c1, ?c2
                   | congruence ].
  Qed.
End iso.
```

You can also easily get your `el` about `list`s, automatically, even:

```
Scheme el := Minimality for list Sort Type.
Check el. (* forall A P : Type, P -> (A -> list A -> P -> P) -> list A -> P *)
```

Does this suffice for your purposes, or are you wanting more?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!